# Error while building ParaView custom app in Windows 10

Tags: qt, cmake, paraview

I have build ParaView superbuild following steps that I found in another question.

Steps to build ParaView superbuild in Windows 10:

```
Install Visual Studio 2015 community with all C++ related tools
Install cmake
Install git bash
Install Ninja
Install Qt 5.9.9 VS2015 64 bits

then :

Open VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt and execute: cmake-gui

ENABLE_qt5 and USE_SYSTEM_qt5
ENABLE_python 
ENABLE_python2

and add: Qt5_DIR = C:/Qt/5.9.9/msvc2015_64/lib/cmake/Qt5

configure
generate
```

Result:

```
Determined source version for paraview: 5.7.0
Enabling cxx11 as requested.
Enabling ftjam as requested.
Enabling nlohmannjson as requested.
Enabling zlib for: hdf5
Enabling szip for: hdf5
Enabling hdf5 for: paraview
Enabling python2 as requested.
Enabling python as requested.
Enabling qt5 as requested.
Enabling paraview as requested.
Building projects: cxx11, ftjam, nlohmannjson, zlib, szip, hdf5, python2, python, qt5, paraview
Configuring done
Generating done
```

Then:

```
close cmake-gui
ninja
```

After a couple hours, it seems to build successfully.

I then download `Clone1` from https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview/tree/master/Examples/CustomApplications

Open `VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt` and execute: `cmake-gui`

Add:

```
Qt5_DIR = C:/Qt/5.9.9/msvc2015_64/lib/cmake/Qt5
ParaView_DIR = C:\Users\user\Desktop\paraview\buildvs2015\install\lib\cmake\paraview-5.7
```

Then:

```
configure
generate
```

And I got:

```
Found Python2: C:/Users/user/Desktop/paraview/buildvs2015/install/lib/python27.lib (found suitable version "2.7.15", minimum required is "2.7") found components: Development 
Found OpenGL: opengl32  found components: OpenGL 
Found ZLIB: C:/Users/user/Desktop/paraview/buildvs2015/install/lib/zlib.lib (found version "1.2.11") 
Looking for pthread.h
Looking for pthread.h - not found
Found Threads: TRUE  
Skipping example: Clone1 example requires PARAVIEW_USE_QT to be enabled. Please rebuild ParaView (or point to a different build of ParaView) with PARAVIEW_USE_QT set to TRUE
Configuring done
```

I have `ENABLE_qt5` and `USE_SYSTEM_qt5` activated, why am I getting this? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Clone1 example from ParaView 5.7.0, not from master.
You can find the sources in

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\paraview\buildvs2015\superbuild\paraview\src\Examples\CutstomApplications\Clone1
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not getting that error now. But after, executing `ninja` in the build folder I get `[8/8] Linking CXX executable bin\paraview_clone1.exe`. When executing `paraview_clone1.exe` I get the error `The code execution cannot proceed because pqApplicationComponents-pv5.7.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem`. The same with `pqComponents-pv5.7.dll`, `pqCore-pv5.7.dll` and `pqWidgets-pv5.7.dll` . Any idea what this could be and what should I do?